# App Engine python flexible environment 3.6 or 3.7?

Tags: google-app-engine-python

On https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ the runtime for the flexible python environment is said to be 3.6. However on https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/runtime it is said to be 3.7.

My build is reported to fail as it depends on a package that requires 3.7 (using `gcloud app deploy`). So at least my build is using 3.6.

Is this an error in the doc or is also 3.7 available in the flex env?

## Update 1

Although the feedback says the default python3 interpreter in the flex env is 3.7, I did have following error when trying to deploy my app when dependent on a module that requires 3.7:

```
Step #1: <my-dep-module> requires Python '>=3.7' but the running Python is 3.6.8
```

When I remove that dependency and I build I also see 3.6 mentioned in the build output:

```
Step #1: ---> f186f86e42ea Step #1: Step 2/9 : LABEL python_version=python3.6 Step #1: ---> Running in 7b76fdee165b 
Step #1: Removing intermediate container 7b76fdee165b Step #1: ---> 482717f31b28 
Step #1: Step 3/9 : RUN virtualenv --no-download /env -p python3.6 Step #1: ---> Running in b1d15ba3568d 
Step #1: Running virtualenv with interpreter /opt/python3.6/bin/python3.6
```

Thus somehow `gcloud app deploy` is building using 3.6 nevertheless?

Comment: I think you're correct, the documentation at the second link is wrong.  I specified `python_version: 3` and got 3.6.10  When I specify `python_version: 3.7` I get 3.7.2.  According to the engine, valid values are currently these `'', '2', '3', '3.4', '3.5', '3.6', '3.7'`

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Python interpreter's version to the latest supported Python 3.x release, which is currently 3.7.2, in the app.yaml file by specifying the `runtime_config` element like so:

```
runtime: python
env: flex

runtime_config:
    python_version: 3
```

You could set it to other versions by specifying 3.6 or 3.5 as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml#general) but 3 at this time refers to 3.7.2.

Answer (score 0):

You can set for App Engine flex any version you want in the `app.yaml` as you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml#general). If you just mention  `3` at :

`runtime_config:
    python_version: <version number>`

It will take by default the latest version possible ( now, 3.7.2 )